# Coldness vs cold

Tags: meaning

When do you use `coldness`? I rarely but sometimes here it in the sense of someone's lack of feelings, for example (like someone's coldness from the inside), but even then I'd say that `cold` is not inappropriate either.

I searched a bit online but did not find serious (enough) arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also dark, darkness.

> I couldn't see because of the dark/darkness.

*Dark* is not an abstract quality; it's the absence of light.

*Cold* is not abstract; it's the lack of heat.

Sometimes it's speaker's choice, but the noun formation using -ness creates a noun from the adjectives cold, dark. One would use the -ness versions when expressing the abstract quality of the *adjectival* version:

His heart was dark. There was darkness in his heart.

Her heart was cold. There was coldness in her heart.

The -ness nouns are modifications of the given adjectives.

Comment: great, thanks, nice comparison with 'dark'

Comment: And saying "I didn't like him because of his cold" means something else.